# Correct use(s) of "Name, Founder"

Tags: word-usage, business-language

When listing a name and title on for example a business card, does "Name, Founder" mean:

- "the founder"
- "a founder"
- Both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how many founders the company has, it's impossible to be sure. Naturally, if they are the sole founder, it means 'the founder'. If there's more than one, it means 'a founder'.

Comment: Meaning if co-founders agree to use "Name, Founder" instead of "Name, Co-Founder" that using "Name, Founder" would be okay since it lacks a "the" or "a", right? Also, if "Name, Founder" occurs more than once in a list in reference to the same entity being founded, for example a list of bios, is "Name, Founder" still okay, or is "Name, Co-founder" the required? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a hard and fast rule. Anyone can give themselves any job title they like.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying it is okay that given two founders of the same company are present in the same list, such as a company bio list, that it still hold true that "Bob, Founder" and "John, Founder" are each read as meaning "a founder" of the company; meaning they're co-founders that decided they'd each like to be referenced as "a founder" on the list, and are not required to be listed as co-founders to be correct. Also, though irrelevant in my opinion, the reference of "Name, Founder" does not preclude it being transformed to "Bob, CEO & Founder" and "John, CTO & Founder." Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any problem with any of that, unless there happens to be some legal attachment to the word _founder_.